# Как изменить размер кадра при повороте видео в Adobe Premiere?

Tags: adobe

Поместил видео на монтажный стол, размером 1280x720. Кадр, как я понял, автоматически также стал 1280x720. Но видео снималось вертикально, т.е. имеет не альбомную, а книжную ориентацию, и чтобы нормально его смотреть, нужно поворачивать его на 90 градусов. Если я в Adobe Premiere поворачиваю видео, то оно обрезается снизу и сверху, т.к. видео становится высотой 1280 пикселей, а кадр остается 720. А по бокам все наоборот, видео по ширине меньше кадра и поэтому остаются черные пространства по бокам. Никак не могу найти в самом Premiere и в инете, как изменять размеры кадра, чтобы они соответствовали размерам видео (в данном случае, чтобы они были 720x1280). Подскажите, как изменить размер кадра.

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта.
1) Увеличить картинку по ширине экрана и сделать панараму снизу вверх точками position
2) Второй вариант создатьт дукбликат кадра и положить его под основной, увеличить его на всю ширину и заблюрить